# Adding Objects from NSMutableDictionary to NSMutableArray

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am new in ios development, I want to add some object from database which I managed to put into a `NSMutabledictionary` and I want to put into a `NSMutableArray` to display in a `UITableView`. Below is my .m file code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    jsonURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost:8888/read_product_list.php"];

    //jsonData = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:jsonURL];

    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:jsonURL];
    [self getData:data];    
}

-(void) getData:(NSData *) response {
    NSError *error;

    NSMutableDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:response options:kNilOptions error:&error];
    //NSLog(@"%@", json);


    jsonArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    /*for(int i = 0; i < json.count; i++){
        [jsonArray addObject:[json objectForKey:];
    }*/

    //NSLog(@"%@", jsonArray);

}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you please add a sample of the response you're getting from your url (the json text you're trying to parse)?

Comment: [{"0":"Samsung LCD 42 TV","Name":"Samsung LCD 42 TV","1":"7900.99","Price":"7900.99","2":"Buy the new Samsung 42 nth TV from Hi-if. available only this coming weekend. ","Description":"Buy the new Samsung 42 nth TV from Hi-if. available only this coming weekend. "},{"0":"iPhone 4s","Name":"iPhone 4s","1":"7000","Price":"7000","2":"Buy a brand new iPhone 4s from Orange with a lot of Features such as Siri, 3G and Wi-Fi.","Description":"Buy a brand new iPhone 4s from Orange with a lot of Features such as Siri, 3G and Wi-Fi."}]

Comment: when i run it with the NSLog it gives the below result, so i wanted to put the result into a NSMutableArray

Comment: 2012-05-29 12:22:42.051 iShop[4829:f803] (
        {
        0 = "Samsung LCD 42 TV";
        1 = "7900.99";
        2 = "Buy the new Samsung 42 nth TV from Hi-if. available only this coming weekend.  ";
        Description = "Buy the new Samsung 42 nth TV from Hi-if. available only this coming weekend.  ";
        Name = "Samsung LCD 42 TV";
        Price = "7900.99";
    }
)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the values of the dictionary then try:

```
jsonArray = json.allValues;
```

It won't be ordered by anything interesting though, so you might want to order it afterwards as well.

But, if this really is your JSON:

```
[{"0":"Samsung LCD 42 TV","Name":"Samsung LCD 42 TV","1":"7900.99","Price":"7900.99","2":"Buy the new Samsung 42 nth TV from Hi-if. available only this coming weekend. ","Description":"Buy the new Samsung 42 nth TV from Hi-if. available only this coming weekend. "},{"0":"iPhone 4s","Name":"iPhone 4s","1":"7000","Price":"7000","2":"Buy a brand new iPhone 4s from Orange with a lot of Features such as Siri, 3G and Wi-Fi.","Description":"Buy a brand new iPhone 4s from Orange with a lot of Features such as Siri, 3G and Wi-Fi."}]
```

Then that's actually an array anyway, so you probably just want:

```
jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:response options:kNilOptions error:&error];
```

Comment: That's why I asked him as well :P This is the most evil pitfall with that kind of questions, we just 'assume' that the OP knows how the actual data structure is. Anyway +1 for being quicker than me :)

Answer (score 0):

To get all values into an array

```
NSMutableArray *jsonArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[json allValues]];
```

To get all keys into an array

```
NSMutableArray *jsonKeyArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[json allKeys]];
```