# How to add Nsmutabledictionary data into Nsmutablearray.?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsmutabledictionary

> i am geting data in a nsmutabledictionay from api and i need to add this data into tableview cell, so i need to convert it into nsmutable array. but when tried to add data from dictonary to aarray it picks only last object of dictonary. pleae look at my code and response.

```
i need to parse stop1 and stop2 address 

 NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];

NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [session dataTaskWithRequest:theRequest
                                        completionHandler:
                              ^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

                                  NSLog(@"Response:%@ %@\n", response, error);
                                  if(error == nil)
                                  {

                                      NSString * text = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: data encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                                      NSLog(@"Data = %@",text);
                                  }

                                  dictionary = [[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil]objectForKey:@"data"];
                                  NSMutableDictionary *temp = [NSMutableDictionary new];

                                  NSArray *IDArray = [dictionary objectForKey:@"docs"];
                                  for (NSDictionary *Dict in IDArray)
                                  {
                                      [temp setObject:[Dict objectForKey:@"_id"] forKey:@"_id"];
                                      NSLog(@"id %@", temp);


                                  }


                                  [getid addObject:temp];
                                  NSLog(@"getid details %@", getid);


                                  if (getid)
                                  {
                                      [_ScheduleRidetable reloadData];
                                  }



                              }];
```

> this is my response which i get in console

```
   id {
"_id" = 573c1beb7051509c0ec94936;
     }
 2016-05-18 14:41:48.641 GGR Driver Staging[11546:6724511] id {
"_id" = 573c17f8261b2bc76e228721;
    }
  2016-05-18 14:41:48.642 GGR Driver Staging[11546:6724511] id {
"_id" = 573c0f20261b2bc76e22871e;
     }
 2016-05-18 14:41:48.642 GGR Driver Staging[11546:6724511] id {
"_id" = 573c0eb4261b2bc76e22871d;
  }
 2016-05-18 14:41:48.643 GGR Driver Staging[11546:6724511] id {
"_id" = 573c0e15261b2bc76e22871c;
    }
   2016-05-18 14:41:48.644 GGR Driver Staging[11546:6724511] id {
"_id" = 573c0d0c261b2bc76e22871b;
     }
  2016-05-18 14:41:48.645 GGR Driver Staging[11546:6724511] id {
"_id" = 573c0c5f261b2bc76e22871a;
  }
  2016-05-18 14:41:48.646 GGR Driver Staging[11546:6724511] id {
"_id" = 573c0acf261b2bc76e228717;
   }
2016-05-18 14:41:48.647 GGR Driver Staging[11546:6724511] getid details (
    {
    "_id" = 573c0acf261b2bc76e228717;
     }
  )


{"message":"success","data":{"docs":[{"_id":"573c1beb7051509c0ec94936","user":{"phone":"9574863210","image":"","name":"user12"},"distance":45123,"bookingNumber":"429r2ckh8pa8","bookingType":0,"paymentMode":"Card","tip":0,"estimatedFare":103.99,"estimatedDuration":"4557","created":"2016-05-18T07:38:12.037Z","stop2":{"address":"New Delhi, New Delhi 110001, India","location":[28.6139391,77.2090212]},"stop1":{"address":"Sector 18, Noida, Uttar Pradesh 201301, India","location":[28.570317000000003,77.3218196]},"destination":{"address":"Gurgaon, Haryana 122001, India","location":[28.459496499999997,77.0266383]},"currentLocation":{"address":"A20A Block, Sector 58","location":[28.6024597,77.3609439]}},{"_id":"573c17f8261b2bc76e228721","user":{"phone":"9988776655","image":"","name":"Chandan"},"distance":5003,"bookingType":0,"paymentMode":"Card","tip":0,"estimatedFare":14.83,"estimatedDuration":"703","created":"2016-05-17T07:44:02.130Z","stop2":{"location":[]},"stop1":{"location":[]},"destination":{"address":"Noida City Center, Noida, Uttar Pradesh, India","location":[28.5748053,77.35633740000003]},"currentLocation":{"address":"A20, A Block, Sector 58, Noida, Uttar Pradesh 201301, India","location":[28.6024597,77.36094389999994]}},{"_id":"573c0f20261b2bc76e22871e","user":{"phone":"9988776655","image":"","name":"Chandan"},"distance":5003,"bookingType":0,"paymentMode":"Card","tip":0,"estimatedFare":14.83,"estimatedDuration":"703","created":"2016-05-17T07:44:02.130Z","stop2":{"location":[]},"stop1":{"location":[]},"destination":{"address":"Noida City Center, Noida, Uttar Pradesh, India","location":[28.5748053,77.35633740000003]},"currentLocation":{"address":"A20, A Block, Sector 58, Noida, Uttar Pradesh 201301, India","location":[28.6024597,77.36094389999994]}},{"_id":"573c0eb4261b2bc76e22871d","user":{"phone":"9988776655","image":"","name":"Chandan"},"distance":9913,"bookingType":0,"paymentMode":"Card","tip":0,"estimatedFare":31.71,"estimatedDuration":"1533","created":"2016-05-17T07:44:02.130Z","stop2":{"location":[]},"stop1":{"location":[]},"destination":{"address":"Noida, Uttar Pradesh, India","location":[28.5355161,77.39102649999995]},"currentLocation":{"address":"A20, A Block, Sector 58, Noida, Uttar Pradesh 201301, India","location":[28.6024597,77.36094389999994]}},{"_id":"573c0e15261b2bc76e22871c","user":{"phone":"9988776655","image":"","name":"Chandan"},"distance":5003,"bookingType":0,"paymentMode":"Card","tip":0,"estimatedFare":14.83,"estimatedDuration":"703","created":"2016-05-17T07:44:02.130Z","stop2":{"location":[]},"stop1":{"location":[]},"destination":{"address":"Noida City Center, Noida, Uttar Pradesh, India","location":[28.5748053,77.35633740000003]},"currentLocation":{"address":"A20, A Block, Sector 58, Noida, Uttar Pradesh 201301, India","location":[28.6024597,77.36094389999994]}},{"_id":"573c0d0c261b2bc76e22871b","user":{"phone":"9988776655","image":"","name":"Chandan"},"distance":5003,"bookingType":0,"paymentMode":"Card","tip":0,"estimatedFare":14.83,"estimatedDuration":"703","created":"2016-05-17T07:44:02.130Z","stop2":{"location":[]},"stop1":{"location":[]},"destination":{"address":"Noida City Center, Noida, Uttar Pradesh, India","location":[28.5748053,77.35633740000003]},"currentLocation":{"address":"A20, A Block, Sector 58, Noida, Uttar Pradesh 201301, India","location":[28.6024597,77.36094389999994]}},{"_id":"573c0c5f261b2bc76e22871a","user":{"phone":"9988776655","image":"","name":"Chandan"},"distance":5003,"bookingType":0,"paymentMode":"Card","tip":0,"estimatedFare":14.83,"estimatedDuration":"703","created":"2016-05-17T07:44:02.130Z","stop2":{"location":[]},"stop1":{"location":[]},"destination":{"address":"Noida City Center, Noida, Uttar Pradesh, India","location":[28.5748053,77.35633740000003]},"currentLocation":{"address":"A20, A Block, Sector 58, Noida, Uttar Pradesh 201301, India","location":[28.6024597,77.36094389999994]}},{"_id":"573c0acf261b2bc76e228717","user":{"phone":"9988776655","image":"","name":"Chandan"},"distance":5003,"bookingType":0,"paymentMode":"Card","tip":0,"estimatedFare":14.83,"estimatedDuration":"703","created":"2016-05-17T07:44:02.130Z","stop2":{"location":[]},"stop1":{"location":[]},"destination":{"address":"Noida City Center, Noida, Uttar Pradesh, India","location":[28.5748053,77.35633740000003]},"currentLocation":{"address":"A20, A Block, Sector 58, Noida, Uttar Pradesh 201301, India","location":[28.6024597,77.36094389999994]}}],"total":10,"limit":8,"page":":1","pages":2}}
```

> This is my api form there i get response.

```
NSURL *theURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://qa.networc.in:1336/api/dispatcher/rideScheduled/:1"];
NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:theURL      cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval:20.0f];

//Specify method of request(Get or Post)
[theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];

//Pass some default parameter(like content-type etc.)
[theRequest setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[theRequest setValue:@"application/json; charset=UTF-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

[theRequest addValue:token forHTTPHeaderField:@"x-access-token"];

NSURLResponse *theResponse = NULL;
NSError *theError = NULL;

NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:theRequest returningResponse:&theResponse error:&theError];
if (responseData == nil)
{

    return;
}

NSDictionary *dataDictionaryResponse = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:0 error:&theError];
NSLog(@"url to send request= %@",theURL);
NSLog(@"%@",dataDictionaryResponse);
```

Comment: what you get in `dictionary` ? by `dictionary = [[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil]objectForKey:@"data"];` this statement ? and what you want from it to display on tabelview ?

Comment: Can you please share web service actual response?

Comment: sir please look at edited question again. i post my response

Comment: yes sir please check it in jsonviewer

Comment: As @Lion said, the line `dictionary = [[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil]objectForKey:@"data"];` is wrong here. You can directly use `NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers  error:&error];`

Comment: do you want id to display in your table view  cell ?

Comment: @Lion sir i want to display id, phone, stop1 and stop2 address in my cell

Comment: In `temp` you're setting the value always for the same key `_id` which overwrites an existing value.

Comment: @vadian sir how will i get it in array form so that i display it on prototype cells

Comment: @sandeeptomar - where u struck

Comment: `IDArray` **is** an array of dictionaries. You can use it directly unless you put the values into a custom struct or class.

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik thanks for your response sir

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding Objects from NSMutableDictionary to NSMutableArray](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10796883/adding-objects-from-nsmutabledictionary-to-nsmutablearray)

Comment: Where is  `NSLog(@"Data = %@",text);` line log?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do like

```
                 getid = [NSMutableArray New];

                    for (NSDictionary *Dict in IDArray)
                              {
                                   NSMutableDictionary *temp = [NSMutableDictionary new];
                                  [temp setObject:[Dict objectForKey:@"_id"] forKey:@"_id"];
                                 // for fetch stop1 and stop2 use like
                                   NSMutableDictionary *stp1 = [Dict objectForKey:@"stop1"] 
                               if ([[stp1 allKeys] containsObject:@"address"]) {
// key exists.
                         [temp setObject:[stp1 objectForKey:@"address"] forKey:@"address"];
                            }
               }


                                NSMutableDictionary *stp2 = [Dict objectForKey:@"stop2"] ;

                         if ([[stp2 allKeys] containsObject:@"address"]) {
// key exists.
                           [temp setObject:[stp2 objectForKey:@"address"] forKey:@"address1"];
                            }

                                 [getid addObject:temp];
                              }

                             if (getid.count>0)
                              {
                                  [_ScheduleRidetable reloadData];
                              }
```

**Step-2**

*on retrieve in tableview*

```
 idname.text  = [getid objectAtIndex:objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"_id"];
  stop2.text  = [getid objectAtIndex:objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"address1"];
    stop1.text  = [getid objectAtIndex:objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"address"];
```

Comment: chek the answer once

Comment: @sandeeptomar - happy to hear bro

Comment: sir one more little bit issue i have, how will i get stop 2 and stip2 address form json response

Comment: sir still i  get only last object in my cell that is " 573c0acf261b2bc76e228717" in every cell

Comment: please look at this issue sir, i am get only last id for everycell

Comment: @sandeeptomar - r u tried my answer bro, it will fetch all values

Comment: yes i am using your answer sir but i get last id on every cell

Comment: @sandeeptomar - check the update answer bro at the same time update your question with my answer part, it is easy to resolve

Comment: app crash sir by this error [__NSCFString objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x16df2a80'  at this line  [temp setObject:[stop1Sict objectForKey:@"address"] forKey:@"address"];

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112263/discussion-between-anbu-karthik-and-sandeep-tomar).

Comment: id's come in correct way but app crash while i parse stops address value

Comment: @sandeeptomar - i checked the some index are address are not available  , check the updated answer bro

Comment: @sandeeptomar - I modified the answer check once bro,

Comment: @sandeeptomar- sure bro I am waiting

Comment: its not working bro, app crash on the same line and i get only first object id in my cell

Comment: sir what is that means of this error [__NSCFString objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x176cb3b0'

Comment: sir why we use for loop to get address if i print stp1 in console it also give me address

Comment: ya you can directly use this , wait I will modifiy my ansewe

Comment: yes bro its working fine now, but i get address only for first object, i need to parse address for every id.

Comment: @sandeeptomar - I checked your JSON bro, in first index only have a address that the reason we add the condition , happy to hear, accept my answer bro

Comment: @sandeeptomar -have a  happy day bro

Answer (score 1):

You are setting value for same key in for loop `[temp setObject:[Dict objectForKey:@"_id"] forKey:@"_id"];`  this statement every time override the value of `_id` so when you add it to `getid` array it have only last `_id` with it's value.

so now, if you want array of dictionary then you can simply put your `[getid addObject:temp];` statement in for loop (at last)

If you want array of it value (array of string), here string means your id like `573c0acf261b2bc76e228717` then you can do something like,

in your `for loop`,

```
  [getid addObject:[Dict objectForKey:@"_id"] forKey:@"_id"];
```

So this will add only ids in getid array. your array will looks someting like : `[573c17f8261b2bc76e228721, 573c0f20261b2bc76e22871e, 573c0eb4261b2bc76e22871d, etc to last id]`

Hope this will help :)

Comment: yes sir , i tried to make it and its work great but, how will i add those string in my tableview cell, ia m using prototype cells

Comment: For that you need to implement `cellforrowatindexpath` delegate method and from that you can fetch value from array using `indexpath.row` considering as index. for exxample if you want to show id in cell label then, `cell.labelId.text = [getid objectAtIndex : indexpath.row];` like wise

Answer (score 0):

```
   Array *IDArray = [dictionary objectForKey:@"docs"];
             for (NSDictionary *Dict in IDArray)
            {
               NSMutableDictionary *temp = [NSMutableDictionary new];
               [temp setObject:[Dict objectForKey:@"_id"] forKey:@"_id"];
                [getid addObject:temp];

             }
```

Comment: sir if i use this method than i get response in string but i need to display it on cell by the help of objectforkey

Comment: Nsdictionary *dict = getid[indexpath.row]; than cell.textLable.text = [dict objectForkey:"id"]; in cellForRowAtIndexPath

Answer (score 0):

because NSMUtableDictionary has only one key，you can

```
for（int i=0,i< IDArray.count,i++）{
    [temp setObject:[Dict objectForKey:@"_id"] forKey:[NSString stringformationWith @"_id%d",i]];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Use this code,

NSMutableArray *tempArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

for (NSDictionary *Dict in IDArray)
{
    [tempArray setValue:[Dict objectForKey:@"_id"] forKey:@"id"];
};

[allValues addObjectsFromArray:tempArray];
```

allValues is also NSMutableArray,

hope its helpful